# Will booting up new redshift cluster from snapshot address memory fragmentation / vacuum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How the process of restoring snapshot internally works in redshift?

Is it a memory restore (disk restore) or sql restore?

If its sql restore, there won't be need for vacuum.

So deepcopy can be avoided by booting up a new cluster from an existing snapshot?

if its a disk restore, how selective table restore works ( Redshift gives an option to choose the desired tables from the snapshot which needs to be restored )

Comment: good idea - but i think you are incorrect in your thinking. memory has nothing to do with it. i think the restore is a straight disk restore and does not optimise in any way. you could easily try it by restoring and looking at some stats? let us know?

Comment: if its a disk restore, how selective table restore works? ... Redshift gives an option to choose only the tables which needs to restored..

Comment: yes good point. also if you resize then it will be redistrubuted on your new size. so try it out as a full restore and see?

Comment: @JonScott : Booting up new cluster doesn't solve the vacuum issue. So it looks like a disk restore. But then how selective restore works